# C++ doesnt overload operator

Tags: c++

For some reason, the custom compare seems to be skipped. Never is the debug string printed and the sorting is off.

Can anyone spot what is wrong here?

```
 bool Communication::operator<(const Communication& second) const
 {
     qDebug() << "Actually sorting";
     return (getName().compare(second.getName()) < 0);
 }

class Communication
{
public:
    bool operator<(const Communication& second) const;
    QString getName() const;
    void setName(QString nm);
    QString commName;
}

void Communication::addComm(vector<Communication*>c)
{
    // This is called for sure
    lg=c;
    std::sort ( lg.begin(), lg.end());
}
```

Edit:
Below my new approach.

```
bool Communication::cmp(const Communication* lhs, const Communication* rhs) const
{
  return (lhs->getName().compare(rhs->getName()) < 0);
}

...error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<Communication*>::iterator, std::vector<Communication*>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your vector contains pointers:

```
vector<Communication*> c
```

but your comparison is for values. You need to implement a comparison for pointers, but this cannot be `operator<` because you cannot overload that operator for pointers. It should be a function or functor.

```
bool cmp(const Communication* lhs, const Communication* rhs)
{
  return (lhs->getName().compare(rhs->getName()) < 0);
}

std::sort ( lg.begin(), lg.end(), cmp);
```

Comment: Thanks. However I now get the error I've added to the original question.

Comment: @RobotRock `cmp` is not supposed to be a member function.

Answer (score 2):

Operators won't be overloaded for operators. If you want to sort a sequence of pointers based on a predicate on the pointees you'll need to use a suitable predicate function, e.g.:

```
 std::sort(lg.begin(), lg.end(),
     [](Communication const* c0, Communication const* c1){
         return *c0 < *c1;
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting a `vector` of `Communication*`, but your `operator<` compares `const Communication&`.